# Container with max-width without leaving a gap after new lines

Tags: html, css

So I have a tooltip that has a `max-width` assigned. But when the text got broken because of some long word, it leaves a big padding on the right side which I don't want.

Is there a way to make the tooltip box "auto adjust" its width to fit the content without breaking the words further more? In this case it is the green box I showcased below.

[image]

```css
.tooltip {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```

Here's the solution with hyphens I am using but it still doesn't look that good. I prefer no word-breaks over size changes.

Any suggestions?

```css
.tooltip {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  max-width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip" lang="en">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using `display: inline-block;` on your tooltip?

Comment: Yes, and it does nothing :/